# Setting more than one variable in cursor not behaving as expected

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview

I have an SQLite database with a table called `author`. I'm trying to pull the `id` and `name` values and pass them to the MainActivity where `id` will be stored as a variable and `name` will be displayed in a ListView.

But this is how the log (and my ListView) looks:

```
[com.example.apple.bookshelf.Author@31e44c75,
com.example.apple.bookshelf.Author@24fe640a,
com.example.apple.bookshelf.Author@2c87d47b,
com.example.apple.bookshelf.Author@2ab52298,
com.example.apple.bookshelf.Author@393a3af1,
com.example.apple.bookshelf.Author@2326b6d6]
```

I can see that the problem is because I'm adding both `id` and `name` to the AuthorList array but not specifying which one to show in the ListView. But how do I do that?

Snippet from DatabaseHelper class:

```
public List<String> getAllAuthors() {

        List authorList = new ArrayList();
    // Select all query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + AUTHORS + " ORDER BY name_alphabetic";

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Author author = new Author();
            author.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            author.setName(cursor.getString(1));
            authorList.add(author);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // return author list
    return authorList;
}
```

Author class:

```
public class Author {

    int id;
    String name;
    String name_alphabetic;

    public Author() {

    }

    public Author(int id, String name, String name_alphabetic) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.name_alphabetic = name_alphabetic;
    }

    // getters

    public int getID() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public String getNameAlphabetic() {
        return this.name_alphabetic;
    }

    // setters

    public void setID(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setNameAlphabetic(String name_alphabetic) {
        this.name_alphabetic = name_alphabetic;
    }
}
```

Snippet from MainActivity:

```
        // connect authorsListView variable to XML ListView
        authorsListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.authors_list_view);

        // create new database helper
        DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        // create new list through getAllAuthors method (in DatabaseHelper class)
        List authorList = db.getAllAuthors();

        Log.i("authors", authorList.toString());

        // create new Array Adapter
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter =
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, authorList);

        // link ListView and Array Adapter
        authorsListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

**EDIT:**

I solved the problem using [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140402/how-do-i-print-my-java-object-without-getting-sometype2f92e0f4) from the comment below. Adding this code to my Author class to override the `toString()` method inherited from the `Object` class did the trick:

```
@Override
  public String toString() {
    return name;
  }
```

Comment: Simple list item layout does that. You should probably have coded a proper layout for your list items, so they don't rely on `toString()`.

Comment: Use generics. If you replaced `List authorList = new ArrayList()` with `List<String> authorList = new ArrayList<>()`, then you'll have seen your problem at compile time.

Comment: Way 1: From Author list, create a new list along with author name alone, and set into the Array Adapter.                                                                                                                                                                         Way 2: Create a custom Adapter class by extending ArrayAdapter.

Answer (score 0):

You are not really using your `Author` class. I suggest that you do the following:

Change your `List` to `List<Author>`:

```
public List<Author> getAllAuthors() {

    List<Author> authorList = new ArrayList<>();
    // Select all query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + AUTHORS + " ORDER BY name_alphabetic";

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Author author = new Author();
            author.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            author.setName(cursor.getString(1));
            authorList.add(author);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // return author list
    return authorList;
}
```

Then in `MainActivity.java` change the line with the `ArrayAdapter`:

```
ArrayAdapter<Author> arrayAdapter =
            new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, authorList);
```

Make sure that `toString()` of `Author` returns the string formatted the way you want.